# Disabling all jslint rules with Inline Comments

Tags: javascript, eslint, jslint

`/* eslint-disable */` is the [inline comment](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#disabling-rules-with-inline-comments) that disables/ignores all the eslint rules in a js file. Similarly is there any way to disable **all jslint rules** with inline comment within a js file?

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR -- No.

You used to be able to [have JSLint ignore sections of code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13175495/1028230), but that was removed no later than [April of 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/599859/jslint-control-comments-selective-ignore#comment22384801_13175495).

Here are some options:

#### Roll your own `ignore`

In [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29014953/1028230), I've shown how to hack JSLint yourself if you *really really* to recreate this functionality. You'd probably have to change some line numbers, but you get the idea.

#### Id any code smell

The real question, however, is what specifically is it that you want JSLint to ignore? Often there's a code smell associated with wanting to skip something that you might, on further consideration, prefer to fix another way. Or if there's a [specific JSLint option](http://jslint.com/help.html) that matches what you want to skip, you could turn that option on.

#### "Quarantine" your code

As an alternative to turning JSLint off for a few lines if you know you want to keep the code, I often put utility functions that, for whatever reason, aren't JSLint happy, in a separate file so that I can have clean files elsewhere in my codebase.