# Is there a way to suppress JSHint warning for one given line?

Tags: jshint

I have a (single) case in my app were `eval` is used, and I would like to suppress JSHint warning only for this case.

Is there a way to achieve that? Configuration, magic comment, ...?

Answer (score 486, accepted):

Yes, there is a way. Two in fact. In [October 2013](http://www.jshint.com/blog/new-in-jshint-oct-2013/) jshint added a way to ignore blocks of code like this:

```
// Code here will be linted with JSHint.
/* jshint ignore:start */
// Code here will be ignored by JSHint.
/* jshint ignore:end */
// Code here will be linted with JSHint.
```

You can also ignore a single line with a trailing comment like this:

```
ignoreThis(); // jshint ignore:line
```

Comment: For anybody trying to get JSHint Sublime Text 2/3 plugins to work, you will need to upgrade jshint specifically in the ST package folder. (I specifically ran in to this with JSHint Gutter)

Comment: Is it possible to ignore a specific error only? eg. maxlen on that specific line yet still detect other errors.

Comment: thank goodness for `// jshint ignore:line` -- works great with `;(function() { // jshint ignore:line`

Comment: The "ignore" option is deprecated, and I get the error "bad option" using version 0.9.9 of JSHint Integration feature in eclipse. Is there an alternative way to do the same thing?

Comment: I got around the `bad option: 'ignore'` by using the specific [option](http://www.jshint.com/docs/options/) for the line I want ignored. In my case I wanted to ignore `if (x == null)` because I want it to equal more than just null and used [`/* jshint eqnull:true */`](http://www.jshint.com/docs/options/#eqnull) in the same function as the `if` to silence JSHint.

Comment: Ignoring a line only seems to work on a formal standalone Javascript line. It doesn't work if you try to apply it to a line within a collection or other datatype declaration.

Comment: That's really a poor way to do it. You should only disabled the one warning you want. You don't want to disable everything.

Answer (score 111):

The "evil" answer did not work for me. Instead, I used what was recommended on the JSHints [docs page](http://www.jshint.com/docs/). If you know the warning that is thrown, you can turn it off for a block of code. For example, I am using some third party code that does not use camel case functions, yet my JSHint rules require it, which led to a warning. To silence it, I wrote:

```
/*jshint -W106 */
save_state(id);
/*jshint +W106 */
```

Comment: And how do I figure out my warning number?

Comment: When you run jshint and get the error initially, the number will be reported.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I forgot I left a comment, so didn't post something after I checked the docs. It isn't, you have to add `--verbose` to the command to get the warning number.

Comment: Alternatively, the answer to [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17535130/where-can-i-find-a-list-of-jshint-numeric-error-codes) suggests checking [messages.js](https://github.com/jshint/jshint/blob/2.1.4/src/shared/messages.js). I found this quite helpful since I use WebStorm.

Comment: WebStorm 8.0.3 shows JSHint warning numbers: http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/WI/WebStorm+135.937+Release+Notes http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-7597

Comment: Good answer as you can ignore specific errors instead of blanket ignores across multiple checks.

Comment: However one warning number specifys a collection of errors of a similar format(See @MichaelJess answer). That could be dangerous potentially.

Comment: All warning, error and info numbers can be found here: https://github.com/jshint/jshint/blob/master/src/messages.js

Comment: there's a way to write this as a single line comment? like `ignoreThis(); //jshint ignore:W080`

Answer (score 40):

As you can see in the [documentation of JSHint](http://www.jshint.com/docs/) you can change options *per function* or *per file*. In your case just place a comment in your file or even more local just in the function that uses `eval`:

```
/*jshint evil:true */

function helloEval(str) {
    /*jshint evil:true */
    eval(str);
}
```

Comment: fwiw, this didn't work for me with 2.1.9 but worked after upgrading to 2.1.11