# JSHint ignore line failing with the message "Bad option: 'ignore'"

Tags: intellij-idea, gruntjs, jshint

Some of the code I am working on dictates the the syntax of various variables and since I want to have JSHint check for camel case in the rest of the file, I'm ignoring it for a single line as follows:

```
grant_type: 'password' // jshint ignore:line
```

However, using this approach which came from another [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12977661/is-there-a-way-to-suppress-jshint-warning-for-one-given-line) fails both in IntelliJ IDEA (13.1.1) and when performing a `grunt jshint` with errors similar to the following:

```
[L128:C0] W106: Identifier 'grant_type' is not in camel case.
?          grant_type: 'password'  // jshint ignore:line
[L128:C45] E001: Bad option: 'ignore'.
          grant_type: 'password'  // jshint ignore:line
```

What should be done to correct this issue in both of the environments?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Update grunt-contrib-jshint to 0.10.0

https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-jshint/issues/122

Answer (score 1):

While not a prefect solution as we still haven't figured out why the `ignore:line` syntax isn't work, we have instead replaced the code with the following directive which disables the [CamelCase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase) check and re-enables it once the relevant block of code has been passed,

```
/* jshint camelcase:false */
grant_type: 'password'
/* jshint camelcase:true */
```