# jshint turn off alert() error doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, jshint

```
jshint: {
      files: [
        'src/js/*.js',
        'Gruntfile.js'
      ],
      options: {
        jshintrc: '.jshintrc',
        devel:true 

      }
    },
```

How to turn off that alert error in jshint? hell I want to turn off that stupid feature off! if possible "use strict" too, too annoying..

Answer (score 0):

There is a way, look [here](http://jshint.com/blog/new-in-jshint-oct-2013/).

here is a little snippet for that:

```
// Code here will be linted with JSHint.
/* jshint ignore:start */
// Code here will be ignored by JSHint.
/* jshint ignore:end */
```

You can also ignore a single line with a trailing comment like this:

```
ignoreThis(); // jshint ignore:line
```

Comment: Can't it be set as a global function? too redundant to type of those stuff.

Comment: I don't see what you mean... what is the problem to write there 2 lines?

Comment: Where should I put that 2 line into? above is my gruntfile.js, I thought I can set the option there? how to actually use the option?

Comment: try to add the relevant file and then use a trailing comment

Comment: look here for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12977661/is-there-a-way-to-suppress-jshint-warning-for-one-given-line

Comment: so I can't use the option in my gruntfile.js?

Comment: What's that link for? it's not related.