# How to disable equal to 0 warnings on JSHint?

Tags: javascript, jshint

I have some JS condition where I use !=0, that means I am looking for a number or string (or any other true value) and not an empty or zero value (jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hjL4eaht/1/)

```
if(x!=0){
    // do something
}
```

So I got a warning because JSHint suggest me to use == to avoid empties, what is absolutely understandable, but I don't need it, so I am disabling it making [eqeqeq option](http://jshint.com/docs/options/) to false.

```
eqeqeq=false
```

but this is not working, I continue getting these warnings, I think eqeqeq is not the correct option.

The warning says: "Use '!==' to compare with '0'."

how can I disable them?

Thank you!

Comment: You could try having JSHint ignore that line in particular. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12977661/is-there-a-way-to-suppress-jshint-warning-for-one-given-line

Comment: Can you post this as answer to accept it?