# Have jshint ignore certain files when building Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, build, makefile, jslint, jshint

I often have this problem when using Twitter Bootstrap with other 3rd-party JS libraries, such as `html5.js` from WordPress' "Twenty Twelve" theme, where the build fails because `jshint` (or `jslint` in previous versions of TB I think) throws an error due to the third-party JS library, e.g.

```
\n##################################################
Building Bootstrap...
##################################################\n
js/html5.js: line 3, col 122, Expected ')' to match '(' from line 3 and instead
  saw ','.
js/html5.js: line 3, col 140, Expected an identifier and instead saw ')'.
js/html5.js: line 4, col 101, eval is evil.
js/html5.js: line 6, col 369, Confusing use of '!'.
js/html5.js: line 6, col 422, Confusing use of '!'.
js/html5.js: line 7, col 61, 'b' is already defined.
js/theme-customizer.js: line 26, col 26, Use '===' to compare with ''.

7 errors
make: *** [build] Error 1
```

I'd like to avoid modifying third-party libraries or modify TB's Makefile, as that'll cause problems for upgrades in the future; is my only option to put 3rd-party JS files into a separate folder.

Is there a way to get jshint or TB's build process to ignore certain JS files (perhaps through some `.jshintrc` configuration I'm not aware of?)?

Answer (score 100, accepted):

So there is an option to ignore files in jshint, but it's not set within `.jshintrc` but rather a separate file `.jshintignore`, which makes sense. However, while jshint will look for `.jshintrc` in your project's subdirectories, `.jshintignore` needs to be in the project root. So with Twitter Bootstrap, `.jshintrc` is in `/js` while `.jshintignore` needs to be placed in `/`.

So to solve the problem in my question `/.jshintignore` needs to contain:

```
js/html5.js
js/theme-customizer.js
```

And that's it!

Comment: Apparently some wild card type magic also works, for example `js/vendor/*` - if you wanted everything under the vendor folder ignored.

Comment: Thanks for posting this -- I was surprised that [`.jshintignore` is not currently documented](https://github.com/jshint/jshint/issues/1745).

Comment: @HolisticDeveloper Indeed, it seems like it'd be a pretty widely used feature in real-world applications.

Comment: This mostly worked for me, but I actually had to put my .jshintignore file in the project root right alongside .jshintrc

Comment: There is an example file in the github project: https://github.com/jshint/jshint/blob/master/examples/.jshintignore

Comment: trying to ignore a whole project (eslint is being used instead) but ```*```, ```./*``` and ```**/*``` have not worked

Comment: @MildFuzz You put those inside of `.eslintignore` in your project root? According to the [docs](http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#ignoring-files-and-directories) that should work.

Answer (score 35):

As a supplement to Lèse majesté's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14741346/1778898), one can also write these comments in your JS and jshint will ignore the code in between:

```
// Code here will be linted with JSHint.
/* jshint ignore:start */
// Code here will be linted with ignored by JSHint.
/* jshint ignore:end */
```

OR if you just want JSHint not to check a single line:

```
 // jshint ignore:line
```

Reference: [jshint docs](http://www.jshint.com/docs/)

Answer (score 15):

The simplest solution for me is I just add `// jshint ignore: start` to the top of whatever file I want ignored