# Notepad++ JSLint Plugin not compiling whole file at a time and How to ignore a particular line in code

Tags: notepad++, jslint

I have installed jslint plugin in Notepad++

I have changed the options maximum no. of errors to 5000 of jslint as attached below image for getting all the errors or scanning whole file but still i am getting only 7 errors.

Secondly is there a way to ignore any particular line\set of lines in code so that jslint not parse it.

i have used

```
   // jslint ignore:line
```

and

```
/*ignore jslint start*/
    //
    //
    //
/*ignore jslint end*/
```

but not worked at all.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
/*ignore jslint start*/
```

to start the block, and

```
/*ignore jslint end*/
```

the end the block of code to be ignored

**References**

- [JSLint: control comments (selective ignore)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/599859/1113772)
- [JSLint: Ignore Section](http://jslint4vs2010.codeplex.com/#ignore_section)

Comment: Except that it doesn't appear to work in the NotePad++ implementation of jslint.