# How to resolve bad property name $promise error in JSlint

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise, jslint

I am getting a JSLint error `Bad property name '$promise'`. I use AngularJS `$resource` to save the data. How can I fix the issue?

My code is below:

```
$ngUser.factory("$userService", [
    "$resource",
    function ($resource) {
        return {
            user: $resource('api/user/', {
                id: '@id'
            }, {
                save: {
                    method: "POST",
                    isArray: false
                }
            })
        };
    }
]);
```

And I am using the service as:

```
user = $userService.user.save({
    name: "George"
});
user.$promise.then(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSLint checks for properties which starts with $ sign. Since most of the frameworks use $ sign as a naming convention for built-in services, it can be ignored.

If you don't want to ignore it, you can use `//noinscpetion JSLint` in Webstorm or [ignore the block of code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/599859/jslint-control-comments-selective-ignore)  using JSLint as following:

```
/*ignore jslint start*/
// block of code
/*ignore jslint end*/
```